# IAM policy to restrict Instance creation not having proper tags allows some ami and restricts some ami both having correct tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-ami

I've been trying to make a IAM policy that restricts creation of an Instance if certain tags are not applied at the time of Instance Creation. The policy is as follows:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:DeleteTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowRunInstances",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowLaunchOnlyWithRequiredTags1",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RunInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:012345678901:instance/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Purpose": "?*",
                "aws:RequestTag/CostCategory": "?*",
                "aws:RequestTag/Env": "?*",
                "aws:RequestTag/CreatedBy": "?*",
                "aws:RequestTag/Owner": "?*",
                "aws:RequestTag/CreationDate": "?*",
                "aws:RequestTag/Expiry": "?*",
                "aws:RequestTag/Name": "?*",
                "aws:RequestTag/Project": "?*"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

This policy works well if I select "Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type" this type of AMI but gives permission denied error if I select "CentOS 7 (x86_64) - with Updates HVM" this type of AMI. Can someone explain why this is so? Thanks!

Comment: That's weird. Does the centos image work when the policy not applied

Comment: Yes..it works fine when policy not applied.